# How to create a new TeX document with a `TeX-master` file-variable set to `t`?

Tags: auctex

When creating a new TeX document, AUCTeX asks what the master file should be, for instance:

[image: AUCTeX asks for the master file]

The value specified is written into the file as an Emacs file variable (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html)). For example, choosing the default in the above example results in the following initial document:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "<none>"
%%% End:
```

If the new file is not going to `\include` other TeX files, it is its own master file. To indicate this, AUCTeX's `TeX-master` option should be set to `t` (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html)). This configuration is stored in the new file as a file variable as follows:

```
%%% TeX-master: t
```

Observe that in contrast to the previous example the `t` is not enclosed between quotation marks.

Suppose that upon creating a new TeX document I am presented with the Master file query shown in the screencap above, namely

```
Master file: (default <none>) ~/
```

What should I enter if I wish to set the TeX-master variable to `t`? Simply writing `t`, thus:

```
Master file: (default <none>) t
```

doesn't work, as this results in a *quoted* value:

```
%%% TeX-master: "t"
```

which is not functionally equivalent to

```
%%% TeX-master: t
```

Of course, I can always edit the file variable after the document is created, but is there a way to generate a correct file from the get-go?

Comment: I don't get <none> as default value. I get "this file" which results in the value t. The logic for finding a default is in the function TeX-dwim-master. It looks for a buffer in the same directory which already has a master file.

Comment: @YoungFrog: I also normally get "this file", but there are circumstances when one is presented with another default option, which may be `<none>` or may be some other value. I don't know what these circumstances are, but it doesn't matter. The important thing is that these circumstances occur. I know it from experience. The question is: *when* these circumstances occur, how can you instruct AUCTeX to set `Tex-master` to `t`?

Comment: Ok I misread the question, I thought you wanted to debug this specific default value (which looks bogus). Back to the question : I don't have an Emacs session at hand to check, but I believe hitting C-g does that.

Comment: @YoungFrog: When I execute `C-g`, a new blank buffer appears without any file-variable definitions whatsoever.

Comment: What's your default value of `TeX-master`?  Did you add the line `(setq-default TeX-master nil)` in your init file?

Comment: @giordano: Yes, the line `(seta-default TeX-master nil)` is in my init file. I don't know what the default value of `TeX-master` is. How can I find out?

Comment: `M-: (default-value 'TeX-master) RET`.  I expect you get `nil`, given the setting you have.  To be honest, it's not the norm that the master file defaults to `<none>`.  Is this always reproducible?  Or does it happen sometimes?

Comment: @giordano: As you expected, the default value of `TeX-master` is `nil`. No, it is not always reproducible. It happens only sometimes, and when it does, the suggested default is not necessarily `<none>`.

Comment: Can you determine under which conditions you get the `<none>` default?  In other cases the default should be `t` (and the majority of cases) and you just need to hit `RET` to select the current file as master file when prompted.

Comment: @giordano: I'm afraid I'm unable to determine the conditions at the present time. However, your and YoungFrog's answers below seem to work, so I'm satisfied.

Comment: @giordano - I can confirm that AUCTeX also included the string `"<none>"` into my a file of mine as value to `TeX-master`.  But I couldn't create a recipe to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @ArashEsbati  I know, it happens to me as well, from time to time, but not so often to push me to solve the issue.  In addition, I can't understand when this happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR version**

Any of these should work. At least they work for me:

- C-a C-k RET (go to beginning of line, kill it, confirm)
- C-a C-k C-m (same)
- M-p RET (insert current file name and confirm)

(The third one won't work in every circumstances.)

**Longer version**:

The relevant bit of code is in TeX-master-file-ask :

```
(let* ((default (TeX-dwim-master))
   (name (or (and (eq 'dwim TeX-master) default)
         (condition-case nil
         (read-file-name (format "Master file: (default %s) "
                     (or default "this file"))
                 nil default)
           (quit "<quit>")))))
  (cond ((string= name "<quit>")
     (setq TeX-master t))
    ((string= name default)
     (setq TeX-master default)
     (TeX-add-local-master))
    ((or
      ;; Default `read-file-name' proposes and buffer visits a file.
      (string= (expand-file-name name) (buffer-file-name))
      ;; Default of `read-file-name' and buffer does not visit a file.
      (string= name default-directory)
      ;; User typed <RET> in an empty minibuffer.
      (string= name ""))
     (setq TeX-master t)
     (TeX-add-local-master))
    (t
     (setq TeX-master (TeX-strip-extension (file-relative-name name)
                       (list TeX-default-extension)
                       'path))
     (TeX-add-local-master))))
```

I suggested in a comment that `C-g` would work but, as you can see, while hitting C-g indeed sets the file as its own master, it does not actually update the file variables accordingly.

On the other hand, doing any of these :

- giving as input the actual name of the file being visited
- giving as input the name of the directory in which the file lies
- giving an empty input

will both set the variable TeX-master and update the file variables.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it the case that 'The third one won't work in every circumstances'?

Comment: M-p grabs the last filename read from the history, which might not be the current filename. IOW : inserting the current filename will always work, but the key sequence I suggested might not do that in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I enter if I wish to set the `TeX-master` variable to `t`?

Just select the current file.